# Picasa Mac: timeline or chronological view?

Tags: mac, picasa

In Windows Live Photo Gallery, there's a timeline view (see below) that shows all the Months/Days that any photos in my collection were taken.  I found this very convenient. Is there something similar for the latest Picasa for Mac?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible, unless the photos are sorted this way on your disk and you use the folder view.
In the albums view, all you can do is sort the albums by date, but then they are not grouped by year/month.
The [picasa timeline feature](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/9923-picasa-the-timeline-feature) is not available in the latest release of picasa mac.